# how to have an error show up upon both field answers being '0'

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to figure out that if a user chooses '0' in both fields, to have an error pop and say that at least one of them must have a quantity filled in.

As you can see beneath: the form fields has one error associated with it, ie, `$maleErr` or `$femaleErr` ...

I wrote something like this:

```
   if (($_POST["male"] === "") && ($_POST["female"] === "")) {
  $quantityErr = "Please fill at least one of the fields, either male or female."
```

}

And added `$quantityErr` to the form fields like this: (it doesn't work for what it's worth. Page just blanks out.

```
    <div class="field">
      <label>* Number of People</label>
      <select class="ui dropdown" name="female">
        <option value="">Gender Female</option>
        <option <?php if ($female === 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
        <option <?php if ($female == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
      </select>
      <?php if(isset($femaleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $femaleErr || $quantityErr . '</span>'); ?>
    </div>
```

**Current Form Fields Without Modifications As Mentioned Above**

```
        <div class="field">
          <label>* Number of People</label>
          <select class="ui dropdown" name="male">
            <option value="">Gender Male</option>
            <option <?php if ($male === 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
          </select>
          <?php if(isset($maleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $maleErr . '</span>'); ?>
        </div>


        <div class="field">
          <label>* Number of People</label>
          <select class="ui dropdown" name="female">
            <option value="">Gender Female</option>
            <option <?php if ($female === 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
            <option <?php if ($female == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
          </select>
          <?php if(isset($femaleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $femaleErr . '</span>'); ?>
        </div>
```

**Current Error Checking Without Modifications As Mentioned Above**

```
   if ($_POST["male"] === "") {
     $maleErr = "# of people (gender male) required";
   } else {
     $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
   }

    if ($_POST["female"] === "") {
     $femaleErr = "# of people (gender female) required";
   } else {
     $female = test_input($_POST["female"]);
   }
```

**Additional Edit**

Can this be made to work instead? Because every time I try to submit the form, it unfortunately submits instead of popping up with the error.

```
  if (($_POST["male"] == 0) && ($_POST["female"] == 0)) {
      $quantityErr = "Please fill at least one of the fields, either male or female.";
  }
```

And this is what is with the fields: (identical for both females and males)

```
<?php if(isset($femaleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $femaleErr . '</span>'); ?>
<?php if(isset($quantityErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $quantityErr . '</span>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should turn on error reporting or investigate your error log file if it is turned on. I say this because the white page you discribe is the result of a parse error. You forgot to change `$femaleErr` to `$quantityErr` on the isset here:

```
<?php if(isset($femaleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $femaleErr || $quantityErr . '</span>'); ?>
```

And if `$femaleErr` is undefined, this code will never run because it isn't set. (I dont see where it is set in your example).

But likely why you're running into a problem is the ||. `print()` expects a string. Your logic operation is invalid, and it would output 1 or 0 (true or false) not the variable that is set if done correctly: `print('stuff'. ($varone || $vartwo) .'otherstuff') //  prints stuff1otherstuff`.

So instead try:

```
$msg = array();
if( isset($femaleErr) )
    $msg[] = $femaleErr;

if( isset($quantityErr ) )
    $msg[] = $quantityErr ;

foreach($msg as $msg)
{
   echo '<span class="error">* '.$msg.'</span>';
}
```

This will check each variable, see if they're set, if so it will add it to a message array. Then the foreach will iterate through the array and print out the corresponding messages. If the array is empty, it will do nothing. An empty array is a valid input for a foreach (just needs to be an array).

Comment: I don't know how to check my error log file, let alone know where it is. But it seems the source of the blank page is the function that I wrote as mentioned in the post above. Upon its removal, the page showed up. Any idea what could be wrong with my function?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean but it is imperative that you find and learn how to use the error log, its a programmer's best friend. If you're on a typical cPanel powered shared host, look for a file "error_log" in the same directory as this script. Also, your code does not have any functions. If you're referencing what I quoted, it is likely because you did not define `$femaleErr`

Comment: no worries - you're not being mean. will check my cPanel right now. But there is a function at the very top. Please look at that. Thank you.

Comment: The code you linked does not have any [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). I'm modifying my answer above to cover what maybe the issue.

Comment: just realized that I'm misusing the word function. Apologies. I meant the first code snippet at the very top though.

Comment: hey ... I appreciate you taking the time to modify your answer and to give a more in-depth answer. The thing is ... I'd rather try to make what I just posted in the additional section in my post above work if that's possible. Hope you don't mind, nor get offended.

Comment: also it turns out that the reason why I was getting a parse error is that it was missing a semi-colon in the thing I wrote.

Comment: If you use what you did, you will get an output of 1. What I set up is a logical way to process multiple errors.

What is the desired output? I assumed you wanted to show both errors if they existed.

Comment: the desired output is that if both male and female fields equals to 0, then the error should pop up that at least one of them needs to be filled in, ie, obviously with a number greater than 0.

Comment: and really? I didn't realize that the output would be 1. How do I get the output to be 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93119/discussion-between-practically-and-user27307254534534534543675765).

Comment: hey, i've added a bit more in the discussion chat ... again, thank you so much for your time. i'm sorry i gotta run again. but will check back as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php if(isset($femaleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $femaleErr || $quantityErr . '</span>'); ?>
```

Here you only display the `$quantityErr` if the `$femaleErr` is set. So it will not be shown.

You could add it as a separate line with its own if check, for instance

```
  <?php if(isset($femaleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $femaleErr . '</span>'); ?>
  <?php if(isset($quantityErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $quantityErr . '</span>'); ?>
```

Comment: that sounds like the right solution. But when I tried to implement it right now, the blank page still persists. So, I removed the function that I wrote, and the page showed up. What could be wrong with the way I wrote my function?